# Transit Visa / Stopover in Istanbul

Tags: transit, transit-visas, us-citizens, turkey, istanbul

I am a US citizen traveling on Turkish Airlines I will have an 8-9 hour layover in Istanbul. How do I apply for a transit visa for this stop over?

Comment: Apply at the official eVisa website and get it in 5 minutes: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/ For a US citizen it will cost 20 USD and will allow multiple entries.

Comment: @HankyPanky Please post answers as answers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby we have a number of duplicates of this question, every time the nationality is different so i can't even close-vote them. But I wouldn't like to add an answer to it, just adds to the count.

Comment: @HankyPanky let's make a canonical then.

Answer (score 1):

I am converting @HankyPanky's comment into an answer.

You need to apply for a visa using the [official Turkish eVisa website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/)  the procedure is relatively fast and easy. For a US citizen it will cost 20 USD today and will allow multiple entries.